# Define method in method_added

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Need a little help with the `method_added` hook.

What I'm trying to do is, i have a class and a module. The class is extending the module and it has some predefined methods. In the module, I'm using `method_added` to redefine the class methods using `define_method`. This is what the basic idea is:

```
define_singleton_method :method_added do |method|
  alias :old method
  define_method "#{method}" do
    send "#{[some_class_method]}"
    old
  end
end
```

Now, the query is, would the `method_added` hook be called when i'm using `define_method` to redefine the class method in there?

Comment: Yeah, tried it!! If i replace the **send** in the above code with **puts**, it works fine, else goes into infinite loop!!

Comment: Because you're adding a method.

Comment: Just to be sure. You want to extend you class with a module that will hook into **class** methods definition process and replace **all** class methods (that will be defined after extending the class with the module) with new ones that will perform some other stuff (like calling other class method) and then call original method. Is that right?

Comment: Anyway, that solution with `method_added` hook doesn't look very nice. Would it be ok to have some method, let's say `wrap_class_methods` that will get list of methods' names and rewrite only these methods. You'll be able to call that method in the bottom of your class and rewrite specific list of methods instead of affecting all class methods at once.

Comment: The **method_added** hook is called when we try to define a new method within it.

Comment: so you want to redefine methods from class via module method method_added, methods from class are available in module through extend?